# Robot as a competent proxy?

Tags: halacha, technology, shlichus-agency, artificial-lifeform

Would those who hold that a minor can serve as an [agent in Jewish law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaliah) (for a *d'var r'shus* - discretionary act, not a *mitzva*) hold similarly for a sufficiently intelligent and self-aware robot? The qualifications for the minor seem to be:

1. He possesses the basic level of *discernment* to consciously accept the task and
2. He has the faculties necessary for preforming it.

Or would a non-human always fail on criterion 1 no matter how much intelligence it could simulate?

(See, for example, the *Sha"ch* on *Choshen Mishpat* 182.)

Comment: Giving something to a robot is the equivalent of putting it on a conveyor belt. The fact that a robot can move and be programmed doesn't make it un"electronic".

Comment: Is a conveyor belt the same thing as a yard? If _my_ yard can accomplish something for me (such as receiving or delivering) then can _my_ conveyor belt do the same? This would mean the robot can at least do things for me as a _chatzer_ [which is equivalent to a _shali'ach_ for some intents and purposes!].

Comment: Well a chatzer is an inanimate object that has certain properties (e.g. being "watched") that can accept. I'm not sure that a conveyor belt is or isn't a chatzer, but assuming it is - it's not movable, while a robot is.

Comment: I don't think a _chatzer_ needs to be immobile by definition. What about a _chatzer ham'haleches_?

Comment: @WAF But there it's moving because you're moving - in your possession the entire time (or at least in your watching capabilities). Either way, that's still very limited: being a Chatzer doesn't help for most cases.

Comment: @yydl what about a robot with a real-time camera builtin? still being watched...

Comment: Btw, isnt this similar to the debate about *matza shmura*, between hand- and machine- made? That is, some hold the machine cant have the correct intent, whereas others hold that the machine does not need the intent, but it can be more precise with the timings and such.

Comment: "Self-aware robot" - by what criteria would you consider a robot self-aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was answered in the original comments.  You don't need a robot to be intelligent like a child. A robot is your property, and your property is a shaliach for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think a robot could be seen as a keli.
if you want to make him shaliah of somehting it would be like puting it one one end of and escalator with the recipient on the other.
for cooking it would be like any other machine today.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are difficulties with a *non-Jew* serving as an agent in Jewish law, to say nothing of a robot.

Comment: Most people hold that the Torah did not give proxy power to non-Jews. But a robot could be more like a child (incapable of higher levels of cognition but still somewhat capable) than like a non-Jewish adult.

Comment: Comparing a robot to a liviing person within Halacha, I think is faulty.  Better to discuss a well trained animal, or in Jewish literature Golems.