# Automated Cooking Machine Programmed

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, gentiles, technology, cooking-bishul

I realize in most situations to have a factory line be "cooked by a Jew" an observant Jew would have to turn the oven on, stove on, or something along those lines.

This morning I saw this article [here (Ars Techica)](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/04/the-worlds-first-robotic-kitchen-prepares-crab-bisque-for-ars-technica/) and while the food prepared in the article is obviously not Kosher (clearly), I was wondering if an observant Jew programmed the robot - would that be considered the same as turning on the oven or stove? Obviously this is not being cooked by a gentile, but maybe a Jew still needs to turn on the stove before the robot can do its thing, regardless of who programmed it?

Comment: Possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/does-robot-golem

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a difference of opinion between contemporary authorities regarding whether and how a Jew's triggering the cooking process using some [indirect electronic means](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44572/remote-control-lighting-of-stove) grants the resulting food "cooked by a Jew" (*bishul Yisrael*) status. Here are some pertinent opinions that I found online, which may not be representative of the full gamut of authoritative positions. (All parenthetical jargon-translations are mine.)

- The [Orthodox Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Union) (OU) provides [a way](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/playing-with-fire/) to deem food produced in a factory *bishul Yisrael* through a Jew turning the ovens on by remote control:

  > Rabbi Yehuda Shain has recently developed an ingenious system whereby the mashgiach (kosher supervisor) can monitor the production from an off-site location. By installing a special device, it is possible to turn the oven on and off through the use of a touch-tone phone.
- [R' Yisroel Belsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Belsky), who is one of the OU's chief authorities, was [cited](http://www.crcweb.org/Sappirim/Sappirim%2025b-Vekasher%20HaDavar%20(Jul%202012).pdf) by R' Eli Gersten providing more detail:

  > Rav Belsky said that it is
  >   acceptable to have the Mashgiach turn on the boiler
  >   remotely, from his cell phone, by dialing in a special
  >   code. ... Also if the *Mashgiach* sets a timer in the
  >   evening to turn on the fire the next morning this is also
  >   acceptable. However, Rav Belsky only allows timers
  >   for a one time use but not if they turn on the oven
  >   again and again, because then the *ma’aseh Yisroel* (action of the Jew)
  >   is lost. Rav Belsky said that a timer for its first use is a
  >   real *ma’aseh* (action), similar to *aisho mi’shum chitzo* ("his fire [directly] via his arrow"), and is
  >   not only a גרמא (indirect action), but subsequent uses are only a גרמא.
- However, according to [R' Moshe Heinemann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Heinemann), the [Star-K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-K)'s chief authority, the use such devices [does not](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-bishul.htm) grant *bishul Yisrael* status:

  > If the action that is done by the *Yehudi* (Jew)
  >   causes an indirect lighting of the oven, that action would not
  >   qualify for *bishul Yisroel*. Hence, dialing a number that in turn
  >   trips a switch that in turn lights an oven would be considered a
  >   “*grama*”, an indirect action that would not qualify for *bishul
  >   Yisroel*.

It seems to me that according to R' Belsky and presumably the OU, a Jew's programming the robot initially to cook many dishes in the future would not cause those meals to be considered *bishul Yisrael*, since the dishes would be only indirect results of the programming. However, if a Jew activates the robot to make an individual dish, then the resulting dish could be considered a direct result of the Jew's activation, like the timer set the night before in R' Belsky's example, and therefore *bishul Yisrael*. According to R' Heinemann, who doesn't consider a remote-controlled activation that *immediately* lights an oven sufficiently direct to grant *bishul Yisrael* status, I think it's unlikely that any sort of programming or activation of this robot, short of manually turning on its stove, would allow its product to be considered *bishul Yisrael*.

Of course, the laws of [*bishul Yisrael*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishul_Yisrael) are complicated (and include many exceptions that are applicable to many practical cases), technology is complicated, and the application of the former to the latter is very complicated. If an issue of this sort comes up practically for you, consult your rabbi.

Comment: I think you are mistaken to compare this to remote operation of the additional fire, which is needed to counteract the nonjewish fire/cooking. Here, we are not discussing a robot in addition to a nonjew. It is simply a robot, who's actions might or might not be traced back to it's programmer. Imagine food getting cooked by itself, which the shulchan aruch discusses when a nonjew unknowingly cooks food.

Comment: This is a good start, but I'm trying to see if by programming the robot as a Jew- are you doing the cooking? I see how a timer would not be okay day after day but the machine being run by a timer may or may not have been designed by a Jew, whereas this would be.

Comment: @ZachLeighton, designing a machine is more remote from the results of its operation than operating it is.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I would disagree in this case. This robot is directly following the instructions you programmed it to do, not be a "dumb" food line. It is not a mass producing food line- it is more like a personal chef.

Comment: @IsaacMoses maybe a more accurate thing than a personal chef would be a "golem". Can a golem cook you food?

Comment: Even if its not bishul yisrael, who said its bishul akum?

Comment: @user6591, and DoubleAA, is there indeed a category of food which is neither *bishul Yisrael* nor *bishul akum* and is permitted? If so, then I agree that a robot cook, when not set up, activated, or assisted by gentiles, would fall into that category. (If there are gentiles involved in its operation, then I think we're back to it being akin to a factory line with gentile workers.) I'm open to a significant edit of this answer, either by you or by me, taking into account sources that you may have.

Comment: @ZachLeighton, I don't get how a machine that directly follows instructions you gave it is different from a "dumb food line." In both cases, there's a similar deterministic but indirect relationship between the program/design, the machine, the ingredients, the activation, and the final product. Are you suggesting that the robot somehow has a status more akin to a person than a deterministic machine - that it has some sense of agency?

Comment: @Isaac see siman 113 siff 5 as I mentioned before when a nonjew who cooks without intention of doing an act of cooking this cooking does not have the status of bishul akum and is permitted. It obviously is not bishul yisroel either.

Comment: I would say yes, the robot has more capability to make decisions on its own than a food line.

Comment: @ZachLeighton I doubt we have any technology yet that could be considered to be "making decisions." Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/robot-as-a-competent-proxy http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22650/does-amirah-lakum-apply-to-robots http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6008/psak-halacha-by-ai