# Does peanut butter need a Hechsher

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, yoreh-deah, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

What’s the Halacha regarding whether Jews may eat peanut butter without a Hechsher? If they buy peanut butter from gentiles, do they require a kosher certification to eat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two questions here, though they are related:

> A.) Do we recommend today that people buy peanut butter without a kosher certification?

Really not a good idea. Today's peanut butters usually contain non-peanut oils/shortenings, which can in turn be processed on lines with animal fats.

> B.) Are peanuts subject to a special Talmudic law requiring Jewish preparation, as is the case for wine, cheese, or milk?

No way. Peanuts are a New World crop. Could they be subject to the rule of *bishul yisrael*, that foods which can only be eaten cooked and are served as a standalone item at a royal banquet, have to be cooked by Jews? I think peanut butter fails on most of those criteria pretty easily.

So we have two reasons why something would need a hechsher: there's a Talmudic law inherently requiring one, or we're just concerned about the way it's made in 2024. A good way to determine between those two categories is to search for "peanut butter" in the [London Beth Din's Kosher Search](https://www.kosher.org.uk/koshersearch) (of course, this only applies to products sold in the United Kingdom).

- Some peanut butters are determined "not kosher." Presumably they are processed on lines that also do not-kosher, or may include not-kosher additives.
- Some are "[approved, though not certified.](https://www.kosher.org.uk/article/what-difference-between-products-are-kosher-certified-klbd-and-those-are-kosher-approved)" The contemporary British rabbis did their homework about how they are made, and concluded it should be fine. But there isn't a rabbi in the factory. You won't find cheese or wine in this category, because by Talmudic decree, those need Jews involved in the manufacture. But "made by non-Jews, with their reputation on the line that the processing aids etc. are all kosher", is kosher enough for peanut butter.
- And some are actually "certified", with the rabbis doing regular inspections.